# Observable isEmpty before completion

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to create a repository that will get data from a cache if it can and if not it will call the network.

I am trying to use functions such as `isEmpty` or `firstOrError`, but they all require the observable to have completed before `isEmpty` emits.  However the observable that emits the items in cache will never complete as it needs to update any changes to the presenter.

Here is what I have so far, which currently doesn't work.

```
getCacheSource()
    .isEmpty()
    .subscribe(isEmpty -> {
          if (!isNetworkInProgress() && isEmpty) {
              dataProviderDisposable = getNetworkSource().subscribe(
                  val -> { /* ignore */ },
                  RepositoryUtils::handleNonHttpException);
              }
          });
```

Is there a way of checking whether the observable has emitted any items before it completes, or force completing the cache observable?

Comment: why not use flatMap and from there return the right items?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I could use Observable.merge to reach the desired effect.

```
//If the network call is not already in progress
if (dataProviderDisposable == null || dataProviderDisposable.isDisposed())) {
    dataProviderDisposable = Observable.merge(getCacheSource(), getNetworkSource())
            .firstElement()
            .subscribe((boosterData) -> {}, this::handleNonHttpException);
}
return getCacheSource();
```

This checks whether a network call is already in progress by checking the data call has been disposed.  If it's not it calls merge to get exactly one element from memory or the network.

If there is data already in memory it will just return this and not call the network.  If there isn't it will call the network.